# Running powershell without useriteraction

Tags: powershell

`start "odopen://sync/?siteId=$siteid17&webId=$webid17&listId=$listid17&userEmail=$upn&webUrl=$URL17&webtitle=$webtitle17&listtitle=$listtitle17"`

How is it possible to run the following command inside Powershell without an appearing popup window or any userinteraction? I've tried adding /ArgumentList "/S", "/Background". Also tried with -WindowStyle Hidden at the end. Appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command as-is basically says "Start the program that opens `odopen://` (OneDrive) links" and can't really be given any silent style instructions. The proper way to configure this kind of thing is through [OneDrive Group Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy), but we can cheat and set registry keys.

The link above goes into detail about how to configure group policy, but also tells us that the specific group policy setting to "Configure team site libraries to sync automatically" sets this registry key:

`[HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive\TenantAutoMount]"LibraryName"="LibraryID"`

And that your LibraryID is in this format, which looks familiar:

`tenantId=xxx&siteId=xxx&webId=xxx&listId=xxx&webUrl=httpsxxx&version=1`

So to put it in a script, I would use something like this, adapted from [Nicola Suter's blog post here](https://tech.nicolonsky.ch/onedrive-automountteamsites/):

```
$tenantAutoMountRegKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive\TenantAutoMount"

$autoMountTeamSitesList= @{
    #Enter your SharePoint libraries to configure here as key/value pairs
    MySharePoint="odopen://sync/?siteId=$siteid17&webId=$webid17&listId=$listid17&userEmail=$upn&webUrl=$URL17&webtitle=$webtitle17&listtitle=$listtitle17"
}

# Check if the key exists and create if missing:
if (-not (Test-Path $tenantAutoMountRegKey)){ New-Item -Path $tenantAutoMountRegKey -Force }

# Add the sites for automatic mounting
$autoMountTeamSitesList | Set-ItemProperty -Path $tenantAutoMountRegKey -Name $_.Key -Value $_.Value
```

This generally takes effect the next time a user signs into OneDrive, though Microsoft warns it may take up to 8 hours to start syncing (Keeps hundreds of users from syncing the same library at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You cannot.

Using `odopen` will always show sign-in window (as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/deploy-on-windows#help-users-sign-in), what you can do is only populate it with data, which is what you are already doing.

If you want to do it silently, there is documentation about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-silent-account-configuration